# react native flexbox stretch issue

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

In react native i want to achieve this effect
[image]

of course all buttons should have same width and height.
For that i use flex box. How can i do it with flexbox ?
I try:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
     flex: 1,
     flexDirection: 'column',
     alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  rows: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  buttons: {
      flex: 1,
  }
});


export default class Home extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
        <View style={styles.rows}>
          <View style={styles.buttons}><Button title="aaa"/></View>
          <View style={styles.buttons}><Button title="aaa"/></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rows}>
          <View style={styles.buttons}><Button title="aaa"/></View>
          <View style={styles.buttons}><Button title="aaa"/></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rows}>
          <View style={styles.buttons}><Button title="aaa"/></View>
          <View style={styles.buttons}><Button title="aaa"/></View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
}
```

}

but that gave me:
[image]

Please help

Comment: `alignItems: 'stretch'`set to `row` should fix that...and in standard Flexbox this is the default

Comment: sorry but i does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set background colors to all your styles, you will see that your layout is working, except that you cannot change the height of `Button` in React Native. Use a [`TouchableOpacity`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html) or a [`TouchableHighlight`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html) instead of `Button`, and the "button" will fill the whole view instead of sticking to the top.